# Facing issue while installing ruamel.yaml

Tags: ruamel.yaml

When I am trying to install ruamel.yaml it is throwing the following error:

```
 ---> Running in 71801483b5a1
Collecting ruamel.yaml
  Downloading ruamel.yaml-0.17.21-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 109.5/109.5 kB 12.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.2.6
  Downloading ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.6.tar.gz (180 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 180.7/180.7 kB 21.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
[91m  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      sys.argv ['/tmp/pip-install-4z0awj5u/ruamel-yaml-clib_ebca93f6ff92409a86d7beb1a0f1b92c/setup.py', 'egg_info', '--egg-base', '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-odj056w3']
      test compiling /tmp/tmp_ruamel_ua_v5oye/test_ruamel_yaml.c -> test_ruamel_yaml compile error: /tmp/tmp_ruamel_ua_v5oye/test_ruamel_yaml.c
      Exception: command 'gcc' failed: No such file or directory
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[0m[91merror: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

It was working previously. I am using docker and below are the commands being used in Dockerfile

```
RUN pip install ruamel.yaml
RUN pip install ruamel.yaml.jinja2
```

Comment: What version of Python is installed in the container? What architecture are you running on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because the C compiler is not installed. One thing you can do is make sure the compiler is installed so that it can compile the `ruamel.yaml.clib` dependency.

You are installing the `ruamel.yaml` wheel, and I cannot see why it is not taking the wheel for `ruamel.yaml.clib`. That might be caused by an architecture or Python version not being available for that architecture.

If your code is not useing `YAML(typ='safe')` or anything else that actually uses the C loader, then you can also do:

```
RUN pip install --no-deps ruamel.yaml
```

Comment: Which one of the the possible solutions did work for you, that might help others ;-)

Comment: RUN pip install --no-deps ruamel.yaml
this is what worked for me... Thanks

Comment: the mention of achitecture helped me, I was building a docker image using alpine which doesn't use gcc